# ¿Cómo iterar correctamente en esta matriz?

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo esta figura y no se cual es mi error ya que puse el codigo de irse llenando los pares e impares

Este es mi codigo para lograr eso hice que tome las filas pares y haga el proceso de llenarlas de izquierda a derecha y de derecha a izquierda que tome las filas impares, porfavor con mi mismo codigo podrian ayudarme y corregir mis errores gracias:

```
    public static void Matriz (int num)
    {
        int filas, columnas;
        filas = 2;
        columnas = 3;
        int [][] Arreglo;
        Arreglo = new int [filas][columnas];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Arreglo.length; i++) 
        {
            if( Arreglo.length % 2 == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Arreglo[0].length; j++) 
                 {
                  Arreglo[i][j]= num;
                  num++;
                 }

            }
            else
            {
              for (int J = Arreglo.length-1 ; J>=0 ; J--) 
              {
                Arreglo[J][i]= num;
                num++;
              }
            }
            
           for (int k = 0; k < Arreglo.length; k++) 
           {
             for (int l = 0; l < Arreglo[0].length; l++) 
             {
                System.out.print("[" +k+ "," +l+ "] = " + Arreglo[k][l]+ "\t");
             }
             System.out.println();
           }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        Matriz (1);
        
    }
    
}
```

Imagen del ejercicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que el primer índice es cero, qué pasa cuando calculas `0 mod 2`? Trata de ser más detallado en lo que no funciona, cuál es el error o por qué la salida está mal. Ve a [edit] y cuéntanos qué falla

Comment: `Arreglo.lenght` siempre tendrá el valor de `filas` osea 2 el cual es par por ende siempre se ejecutara el ciclo `for` dentro del `if` obviando `else` otro detalle es que el primer `for` debería cerrarse antes del uso del par de for con lo que imprimes las matriz

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el comportamiento esperado y el obtenido. No olvides además que la depuración es tu mejor amiga aquí.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por recalcar mi error ya lo corregi

Comment: SI la respuesta que está abajo te sirvió, márcala como aceptada. Si tú mismo llegaste a la solución, compártela como respuesta (la escribes abajo en Tu Respuesta). Te votarán positivo si es una buena solución y tú mismo podrás marcarla como aceptada en un rato

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto una posible solución, en la cual se dibujará según el número de filas y columnas que se ingresa.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado= new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean derecha=true;//Para alternar la barra vertical | entre izquierda y derecha
        System.out.print("Ingrese el numero de columnas: ");
        int columnas=teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese el número de filas: ");
        int filas=teclado.nextInt();
        
        for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
            }
            else{
                if(derecha){
                    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
                        if(j==(columnas-1))System.out.print("|");
                        else System.out.print(" ");                        
                    } 
                    derecha=false;
                }
                else{
                    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
                        if(j==0)System.out.print("|");
                        else System.out.print(" ");                        
                    }
                    derecha=true;
                }                             
            }
            System.out.println("");            
        } 
    }
```

Si ingresamos el número de columnas=6 y filas=9, obtenemos el siguiente dibujo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]